# Exporting grid view data into Excel

Tags: c#-4.0, export-to-excel

Using Visual Studio 2010 with Server Management Studio 2008 I have made a feature through which a teacher can see the results of all students from all years:

By drop down selection it shows data in grid view, with a button for the teacher to see the selection in an Excel sheet. For some selections there is a lot of data so it takes time.

Now my client does not want display of grid view in the page but direct export into Excel based on the selection on drop down.

Can any one help me to do this.. and would it make my page load a little faster?

Comment: I changed the property visible to false..But i dont know if it will reduce its loading time..?

Answer (score 1):

first write stored procedure in ssms to retrieve the data.
It should be like

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [Retrieveresult] (@selectedfield nvarchar(50))
   AS  
   BEGIN  
   select * from students where condition=@selectfield
   END
```

then in visualstudio

```
   oConn = new SqlConnection();
   oConn.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Retrieveresult");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     oConn.Open();
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selectfield", System.Data.SqlDbType.nvarchar(50))); 
    command.Parameters["@selectfield"].Value="selected value from gridview"
   IDataReader oDr;
    oDr=command.executereader();
  while(oDr.read())
     {
       Get the corresponding values in the objects 
      }
```

Comment: give your connection string for your db,refer this for giving connection-http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: Can you help me in this...Because I found my loading problem is not because of this but because of my some coding loops..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947870/bindingdata-into-table-according-to-selection-in-the-dropdowns